# Having issue deleting a specific row in datatables

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatable, datatables

I want to do is after i add a data in the table i have a choice to delete it or not in the action column.

My problem is if i press the delete button on a specific row that i want to delete it delete some of the content on the table that wasn't suppose to be deleted. Sometimes it delete all the content of the table.

script: http://jsfiddle.net/4GP2h/5/

```
 oTable = $('#myTable').dataTable();

       var data = [
             $('#name').val(),
             $('#age').val(),
             $("#gender:checked").val(),
             "<button class='delete'>Delete</button>"
          ];

          oTable.fnAddData(data);



$('.delete').click(function(){
    var row = $(this).closest('tr');
    oTable.fnDeleteRow(row[0]);
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each time you create a row, you are binding another `delete` event on top of the deletes already in place. So if you make 3 items in the row, the delete bindings look like:

```
ROW1 // <- Deletes on ROW1 'Delete' clicks
ROW2 // <- Deletes on ROW1, ROW2 'Delete' clicks
ROW3 // <- Deletes on ROW1, ROW2, ROW3 'Delete' clicks
```

So clicking `delete` on ROW1 will basically call delete on every row created after it too.

The fix is to move your `$('.delete').click(function(){...});` code outside the `save` event so you are not stacking on delete bindings every time a new row is saved/added.

But also, since you are dynamically adding new DOM elements, we will want to watch for delete events a little differently so that we can bind the `delete` code to any newly added buttons/rows.

Now your code should look like:

```
// Moved outside save function to reference other places
oTable = $('#myTable').dataTable();

$('#Save').click(function () {
    if ($('#name').val() == '' || $('#age').val() == '' || $("input[name='gender']:checked").val() == undefined) {
        $("#dialog-confirm").dialog("open");

    } else {

        var data = [
        $('#name').val(),
        $('#age').val(),
        $("#gender:checked").val(),
            "<button class='delete'>Delete</button>"];

        oTable.fnAddData(data);
    }
});

// Moved outside save function and changed how the event bindings occur
$(document).on('click', '.delete', function () {
    var row = $(this).closest('tr');
    oTable.fnDeleteRow(row[0]);
});
```

You can see the working version [here](http://jsfiddle.net/4GP2h/7/)